# How to find locator of element similar as getText() in automation

Tags: java, selenium, mobile, automation, appium

How to find locator of element similar as getText() in automation

[I am testing app module in which there is day ruler starting from 1 to 50 and every time I go to that module day changes within the range mentioned above. So how can I get element value (ID, Xpath, link etc.) So that its element will be detected and its value will be pass in the below loop. Now I have store hard core day value '38' in 'j'. But I want to use dynamic value for 'j' so that it will decremented till day 1]

[Find attached image for reference][1]

```html
for (int j = 38;  j >= 1 ; j--) 
  {
   System.out.println(j);
  if (j >= 2) {
   Thread.sleep(2000);
   By day38 = By.xpath("//*[@text='"+j+"']");
   Thread.sleep(2000);
   objWrapperFunctions.mobileClick(day38);
   } else {
   Thread.sleep(2000);
   By day1 = By.xpath("//*[@text='1']");
   Thread.sleep(2000);
   objWrapperFunctions.mobileClick(day1);
   break;
   }
  }
```

Comment: Update the question with the HTML of the element for which you want to _get locator value_

Comment: @DebanjanB please check added image in Answer for reference. Its an app

Comment: You posted the image in an answer instead of editing the question and adding it there. Please update the question with the image.

Comment: Are you wanting the currently selected day? e.g. 42 in your pic? My guess is that has a unique class applied to it since it looks different than the other numbers. Have you tried using that class to build a locator?

Answer (score 0):

As no html is posted But,

```
// Case 1=> If we assume you get dynamic day based on below logic

    String dymamicDay=driver.findElement(By.id("someIDforDay")).getAttribute("value");

// get int for String read

    int dDay =Integer.parseInt(dymamicDay);

// Pass dynamic value for j in loop

    for (int j = dDay;  j >= 1 ; j--) 
            {
                System.out.println(j);
            if (j >= 2) {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                By day38 = By.xpath("//*[@text='"+j+"']");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                objWrapperFunctions.mobileClick(day38);
             } else {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                By day1 = By.xpath("//*[@text='1']");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                objWrapperFunctions.mobileClick(day1);
                break;
             }
            }

// Case 2=> If we assume you get dynamic day based on below logic

    List<WebElement> dynamicDay=driver.findElements(By.id("someIDforDay"));

// get no of days from List.size()

    int dDay =dynamicDay.size();

// Pass dynamic value for j in loop

    for (int j = dDay;  j >= 1 ; j--) 
            {
                System.out.println(j);
            if (j >= 2) {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                By day38 = By.xpath("//*[@text='"+j+"']");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                objWrapperFunctions.mobileClick(day38);
             } else {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                By day1 = By.xpath("//*[@text='1']");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                objWrapperFunctions.mobileClick(day1);
                break;
             }
            }
```